# appearance problem using Ajax HtmlEditorExtender

Tags: htmleditorextender

i'm using HtmlEditorExtender in asp.net project. it works well but each button apears twice - The image of each button also includes the icon of the next button, but when clicked it does the action of the original button only.

[that's how it looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOeT4.png)

Thanks for any help